# Oracle jobs monitoring under certain schema users with functions

Tags: database, oracle, monitoring, scheduler, jobs

Just started rewriting of oracle jobs monitoring.

Currently which I'm using is that Nagios is calling two different functions to check DBMS and Scheduler job statuses.

What i'm checking now:

**DBMS:**

1. if job is broker.
2. if job worked longer then expected(actually this is not working correctly 
   because i cant determine any middle or approximately time which it takes)
3. if it executed late, not on time.
4. ok, in case non of above was true.

All this data is collected from `sys.dba_jobs` and custom conf tables

**Scheduler:**

1. count of failures in given interval
2. too few runs in given interval
3. worked for too long then expected i'm pretty sure that all result expect count of failures are not accurate. this data is collected from `SYS.DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` and custom conf tables.

**What is my gain:**

1. avoid useless conf tables
2. need to monitor jobs without custom confs for each jobs, because there always is risk to don't add data about job in table or add incorrect data.
3. i need to somehow get accurate data for each job how long it could be take for execution and how many times had to be executed for given time.

If anyone has produced task like this please help or give some advice or source code where I can take a look and modify for my DB.